# Add the ability to flag your own post for moderator attention

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderation, flags

I asked a question yesterday that is no longer relevant and have voted to close it as such.  I was thinking that flagging it for moderator attention would be a good idea to expedite the process, but do not have the ability to flag my own question as such.

I only have the option to edit, close, and delete...

**EDIT**
Another potential option is on the vote to close option.  If the OP votes to close the question, maybe it should not require the 5 votes to do so?

Comment: Normally, a picture is worth a thousand words, but on the Web a link is worth a thousand pictures.

Comment: I closed that one out for you.  Please ask another question if you want me to close this one as well. :)

Comment: @Bill: I'm not asking this question for a moderator to go in and close that question.  I'd like to have the feature in general that allows me to request a moderator to come in and do it for me.

Comment: @Bill: So does that mean a link is worth a million words?

Comment: @RSolberg: I know, I was just joking.  @gnovice: According to my calculations. :)

Comment: @gnovice: According to hard drive vendors, yes.  But the software community insists that a link should be worth 1,048,576 words.

Comment: @Bill: sorry...  Not trying to be super defensive here...

Comment: @R: No worries.  In all seriousness, I don't know why you can't flag your own posts. It seems like it would be slightly more code to prevent it than to allow it. (I haven't seen the SO code, so I can't speak definitively.)

Comment: i think this is the most "meta" post i've seen yet... until you put a screen shot of this question into another question at least...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now this is one I'm actually in favor of.  It allows you to bring mods to the question in the case of a rollback war or other hijinks.  There's no reason it *shouldn't* be there.

Comment: @Pesto: I knew it was only a matter of time before we found something we could agree on!

Comment: @RSolberg: Is that what this is all about: trying to get my attention?  You could've just sent me a little note saying "Do you like me (circle one)? Yes No Maybe".

Comment: @Pesto: I'm sure that it would come back with a "hell no"...  Figured I'd save a note or two...  I always figured you shouldn't ask a question you know the answer to and don't want to hear it anyways...

Comment: @RSolberg: Honestly, I don't care about you one way or the other.  I'm sick of the thinly-veiled **He Who Shall Not Be Named** questions, and have a standing disagreement with you on the community consensus thing, but that doesn't mean we can't hold hands and walk down the beach together.

Comment: @Pesto: I think that there are far more reasons why the hand holding and beach thing just wouldn't work out.  There are obviously two distinct sides here on some of the edits and if you look at the post I'm trying to get closed, I even say that I consider that matter closed.  I think its pathetic it comes down to waiting for mommy and daddy to rule on things.  If we can't be civil and be patient for a day or two while folks sort out what is and what is not, it comes down to "thinly veiled" questions.  I hate that too...

Comment: GET A ROOM YOU FREAKS :)

Comment: I wish I could upvote a comment thread :p

Comment: @jeff: I think I'll take a rain check, but thanks for working on this one :)

Answer (score 6):

I actually thought about posting this one a few hours ago myself. This would be very helpful to get moderators to [move your question to a different site](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/migrate-questions-between-websites/), as well as review it for rollback wars and possibly even appeal a close vote (though this might get abused).

Comment: +1 I have 2 questions on serverfault that should be moved to SU and no way of getting that to happen

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... this begs the question of why can't we close a question once an answer has been provided and accepted?  That would resolve the issue by allowing you to accept an existing answer and then close the question to further answers...