# Let me vote to move my own questions to a different site (SO | SU | SF)

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, ownership, migration

I recently posted about problems with ASP.NET and IIS in Stack Overflow thinking it was a program related problem but it became evident that it was probably ServerFault material.

Several others (2) closed it with the option to move it to SF but i was frustrated by the fact that as the owner i had no way to move it myself and could only vote and wait for 2 others (5 total) to move it.

Does anyone think it would be a good idea for the owner of a question to have more "pull" to move a question than others?

Perhaps put a softy of it can only be moved once to discourage ping pong with questions.

Answer (score 7):

Just flag for moderator attention and ask that they move it.

---

Hmm... maybe not an exact duplicate, but you might want to read: [Migrate my questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5752/migrate-my-questions)

Comment: I think their concern is that it takes time for a moderator to view it and then move it...

Comment: This is what I did to move this question to meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17210/why-dont-people-upvote-questions-they-answer

Comment: That is the point of the suggestion. I don't think i should have to bug a Moderator for a question I know goes somewhere else.

Comment: @Crash893: but you *should* have to. When your question goes, so do any answers attached to it - you're taking them along for the ride, whether or not their authors approve. This shouldn't be done willy-nilly... (Note that if you don't have any answers, you can just delete the question and re-ask it on the correct site)

Comment: @Shog9 I don't seem to see why they would have a problem with there question moving to different site. In most of the cases the replies are simply telling you to move your question to the other site. I don't think there is any implied sanctity to replies only to questions am i wrong?

Comment: Sanctity? Too much, IMHO, but still precious little. And to the extent that the wishes of a question's owner should be respected, so  should the wishes of an answer's author. And really, in the cases we're discussing, it's the question's author, not the answers', who screwed up. But in practice, it's rarely an issue, so really, you should be able to flag a moderator down and get them to move it quickly.