# Moving questions as the author

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, migration

In [Let me vote to move my own questions to a different site (SO | SU | SF)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17581/let-me-vote-to-move-my-own-questions-to-a-different-site-so-su-sf), the asker wants to know why he can't vote to close his question for it to be moved. [Migrate my questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5752/migrate-my-questions) was successively asked.

I've voted for a couple of my questions on Stack Overflow to be moved, now that there is a more directly-better place for them to live (e.g. *Super User* or *Server Fault*).
Why can't I, as the question author, move it on my own? Shouldn't I not need other approval to move it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree, if you can close your own questions, you should also have the ability to migrate them. It would also make things a bit easier for the moderators.

Answer (score 1):

[What alex said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23279/moving-questions-as-the-author/23280#23280) - with the provision for some sort of limit on the number of moves and/or time between moves.

Answer (score 1):

I agree the ability to move authored questions between sites would be very helpful. Sometimes I make a post and realize I was on the wrong site.