# Should we migrate questions to an on-topic site if the asker requests?

Tags: discussion, migration, old-questions

I noticed this old question on SO in the flag queue:

[Sending email with attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541889/sending-email-with-attachment#question)

The author flagged it, and asked to move it to http://drupal.stackexchange.com

It is **on topic** in the target site, it is most likely **wanted** on the target site.

However, it is already answered and solved. Moving it is not likely to add anything.

What should be done when an author flags an old answered question to be moved to an **on topic** site?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25399/when-the-op-votes-to-close-their-own-question-as-belongs-on-immediately-m  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23279/moving-questions-as-the-author

Comment: I'm firmly of the view that old, answered questions should **not** be migrated - it helps neither the question nor the target site.

Comment: @ChrisF Whether it helps the target site is up to users of the target site to decide. Sometimes such old questions do help, sometimes they don't. What doesn't help is when someone who isn't familiar with the target site decides to migrate an question without consulting anyone — more often than not it is indeed detrimental to the target site.

Comment: @Gilles - you raise a good point, with which I agree, but I tend to use the rule to do just what you suggest - make people think and consult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meh. If it's *on-topic* on the site where it currently sits, then what's the point? It's just busywork.

The exceptions would be borderline questions (where there's some visible controversy regarding the suitability of the current host), and questions where the OP doesn't feel totally satisfied with the answer(s) received. Even then, demonstrating that the question will do better on the destination should be the responsibility of the asker / person flagging: a flag that just sez, "please move" doesn't do much to motivate.

Answer (score 1):

If it is wanted on the target site, it should be migrated.

Note that the definition of “it is wanted” is “habitual users of the target sites (e.g. moderators) want it”. It is not “I've occasionally browsed the target site and I think the question would work there”.

Answer (score 0):

The question is on-topic for Stack Overflow, it is a relatively old question, and (considering what being asked) it would not have better answers, as there aren't other modules that allow to send emails. To be more precise there aren't other modules, considering the generic OP's requirements; there are modules for sending email notifications to users, but those send notifications as result of specific events.

If the user is not happy with the answers, he can offer a bounty, but moving the question on Drupal Answers would probably not increase the probability of getting better answers.