# Stack Exchange Etiquette - switch sites

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I am getting no response to a question in Health.SE and someone suggested to post it in Biology.SE. What is the best way to proceed? Post both places? Shut down one, open the other?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5752/migrate-my-questions

Comment: You might want to make sure your question is on topic on Biology before you do anything.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your question, click on "flag", select "in need of moderator intervention", and in the text box, type something like "I want this post to be migrated to Biology.SE".