# Reopen Question incorrectly closed as Duplicate?

Tags: support, closed-questions, moderators, questions, reopen-closed

So I asked a question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6201/) about finding out the reputation that has been granted based upon the tags of questions one has asked or answered.  The question was closed as an Exact Duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6153/) question; the problem is that it is CLEARLY not an exact duplicate.  My question had to do with discovering the amount of reputation awarded based upon tags; the "exact duplicate" had to do with showing the tags separated by question and answer, with nothing to do with reputation.  The concepts are completely different.

What can I do to get this question reopened?  It is a completely valid request, which is completely different from any other question asked on this site.  While other questions ask things about tags, this question asks something about tags which no other question on this site does.  I have nominated the question for reopening, but since it was closed by a moderator, it didn't go through the normal "nominate for close" process that normally involves a bit of discussion; nobody really had the opportunity to LOOK at the question, since it was so aggressively closed by the moderators (and everyone will now assume that it's invalid, since it was closed).

Other than hoping for 4 others to actually read the question and the (false) duplicate and nominating for reopen, is there anything else that can be done to reopen this question?  And in general, is there any way of bringing the incorrect moderator closure to the attention of the moderators other than waiting for 4 other reopen votes?

Comment: I don't have the rep to reopen else I would.

Comment: Flag for moderator attention, perhaps?

Comment: @JeffYates: yeah, I thought of that, but I can't flag my own question...

Comment: OK, I reopened it. In the future, you might consider editing the question and explaining why it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @KyleCronin: excellent, thank you for the advice.  Have you considered posting that information as an answer?  :-)

Comment: Iconic to notice first thing that this post itself is marked with... **[duplicate]**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reopened the question in question, but for future reference people *can* and *should* appeal their posts being closed if they don't feel that it was done correctly. In the case of duplicate questions, the best solution is to edit the post, include a link to the supposed duplicate, and a short explanation of why your post is different. In order to be relevant when the post is reopened, the blub should not reference the fact that the post is closed or request that it be reopened - the intent will be obvious enough.

This procedure holds for other close reason as well - if your post is closed as "subjective", explain what sort of objective answers you seek, etc. There should be enough mods/users with 10k+ rep around to ensure that it gets reopened in relatively short order.

Answer (score 3):

Well posting it here will bring it to the moderator's attention.

I was going to suggest you flagged the post, but I've just checked one of my closed questions and there's no "flag" link (in fact [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5296/add-the-ability-to-flag-your-own-post-for-moderator-attention) covers that).

Comment: I'm amused that your answer is basically that this question is an answer; very meta!  :-)