# Should such questions be closed?

Tags: discussion

Admins, mods and users. Please look at the following links, read the comments and help decide if such questions should be closed.

[C++ character count (Project Euler 17 wrong answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824332/c-character-count-project-euler-17-wrong-answer)

[Incorrect string count Project Euler 17 using c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808732/incorrect-string-count-project-euler-17-using-c)

Comment: "Yes" is the answer to this question. But you got answers on those questions, anyway.

Comment: This question should be closed because it fails to ask a clear question. What it is about the linked questions that make them interesting subjects?

Comment: You accepted an answer on your first question, and got an answer on the second.  What's the problem?

Comment: @RobertHarvey You left a similar comment [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118848/where-to-argue-that-a-question-was-closed-incorrectly#comment-312584) -- why would "you already got an answer" be a reason to leave a question closed? A question should be open if it's a good fit and closed if it isn't -- that's it

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: See my posted answer there.

Comment: For better results, you should ask this question differently. Firstly, don't make it about your closed questions. That'll make it look like you are just complaining about having your questions closed. Instead, compile a list of similar questions showing that it happens consistently to different people. Secondly, point out (by specific question examples) that the policy isn't being consistently enforced. Point out that there are many questions not being closed that aren't really different from the ones that are being closed.

Comment: Thirdly, don't say: "stop closing these questions", instead ask "what's the appropriate venue for such questions." I think you'll get more useful response then just: "no, we won't stop closing these questions". Fourthly, point out how confusion on this issue is causing bounces between the different se sites.

Comment: Lastly, and most minorly, this isn't a feature request. Those are for changes to the actual software not a change in policy.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: Thanks for clearing that out. I was not looking for answers. I just wanted to discuss, what was I doing wrong. Yes, it was a debugging question, but a close look at it it revealed that I did not count certain parameters correctly.<br/>
The reason why I thought that this is a good question is because lot of people try to solve project euler problems and they get stuck because they did something wrong. The answer to this might just solve their issues like in my case I was not adding 'one' to hundred.

Comment: @Winston Your advice assumes the OP *wasn't* just complaining about their questions being closed. Which may or may not be the case.

Comment: I also don't understand why I got 5 down votes just to ask this question when AnnaLear a mod asked me to post this question here.

Comment: @SameerShah: That's the risk you take posting a meta question. :)  I wouldn't sweat it; I upvoted earlier to counter some of the downvotes.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I am not complaining why only my question got closed. I do think that Winston Ewert's advise would be the one that I would like to take.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: :) I think its just being done for pointing fingers and questioning methodology, which is not right.

Comment: There I go again, I got one more downvote. :)

Comment: @Sameer Questioning methodology is "not right"? What are you doing here, then? And just to be clear, I agree with Winston's advice completely.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I meant down voting for questioning methodology is not right.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> @SameerShah Since you have a problem in your code, Stack Overflow is the right place for the question. However, questions that just provide a large amount of code and ask the community members to debug it don't tend to do very well here. SO is not a debugging service. In addition to that, your question is very specific to your situation and is unlikely to help future visitors (since they won't be making the program the same way and would be unlikely to make the same output formatting mistake you did. This is why your first version of this question (and shortly this one) are closed as "too localized". – Anna Lear♦ 1 hour ago

It might be different if you could say what the expected output was to help narrow it down, but there's really nothing anyone can do but go through an extended debugging session with you.  That's not really a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This link helped a little too.
http://www.quora.com/Why-does-StackOverflow-have-such-a-prickly-community