# What to do about non-duplicate question about to be closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I'm a little concerned about a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499652/windows-forms-webbrowser-control-not-supporting-double-click) I recently asked.

Someone came along and voted to close as duplicate but it seems that was done without reading the two questions (you can see the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826369/how-to-detect-double-click-on-webbrower-control)). Granted, if you look at the core of the title (double-click on the WebBrowser control in .Net) it's easy if you are skimming to think they are duplicates. However, if anyone would read the two questions they would see one is about implementing some custom functionality while the other (mine) is about finding out why default functionality is not working after the install of some Windows updates.

Funnily (or sadly) enough, there have been a total of four votes to close (at the time I write this) all citing the same question as a duplicate. How can it be that there are so many people so eager to close that they don't read the contents of the two questions. I feel like there are people blinding following others just to be part of the 'close party.' However, in the end, it doesn't help the site to become stronger.

So, what can be done about questions just about to be wrongly closed as duplicates? Should we wait until they are closed and bring up the issue here? And hope someone will re-open them?

As a side note, I saw a comment [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6211/reopen-question-incorrectly-closed-as-duplicate) from Kyle Cronin saying to indicate why it was not a duplicate. I did this but the duplicate votes keep rolling in.

Comment: Flag it. Explain why it isn't a duplicate

Comment: @CodyGuldner Thanks. I've actually never used flags before and didn't really know what they were for. Now I know and I've used it here.