# Show that a post has been flagged as spam or needing moderator attention

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags

It would be helpful to actually see on a post that it's already been flagged for e.g. moderator attention or as spam.

Otherwise, folks might be flagging the same post over and over again as spam for instance.

This indicator should be visible only to those SO members who are able to flag it as offensive, spam etc. (it's dependant on your reputation, right?) - don't show it to others.

Marc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having different people flag something over and over again (say as spam or offensive) sounds like a good idea though.

If you have an indicator saying that it's been flagged, then others may be less likely to flag it themselves because, hey, someone else has already done that.

But get different people flagging it, then it's more likely an actual problem. Instead of say, accidental, vengeful or spiteful flagging.

Answer (score 4):

We used to show offensive / spam flag counts and it resulted in a lot of angst and complaints.

We have concluded that there is zero positive value in showing these counts to anyone but moderators.

Comment: It would be helpful for moderators to be able to see the presence of flags on the question itself, rather than needing to refer to a separate list.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to see this information on your my own posts, if I have flagged that post already myself (thanks to [Add the ability to flag your own post for moderator attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5296/add-the-ability-to-flag-your-own-post-for-moderator-attention)). I would, for example, be able to see how many more votes are needed before my post is closed or deleted.