# Visual indication of questions you have flagged for moderation

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show that a post has been flagged as spam or needing moderator attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7275/show-that-a-post-has-been-flagged-as-spam-or-needing-moderator-attention)

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7275/show-that-a-post-has-been-flagged-as-spam-or-needing-moderator-attention) post refers to a global indication of a question being flagged and has been declined, however would it be possible to have a way of showing which questions you have flagged?

I often find myself looking at the same question more then once, and can't remember if I have already flagged a question or answer. Some visual indication somewhere that you have already done so should also help with running out of flags for the day.

Edit: As Kyle pointed out the system doesn't allow you to flag twice when you try and submit. I am keeping this as a feature-request since others indicated they would like this feature.

Comment: A "flagged by me but declined by a moderator" indicator would be nice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, flag it again. If you've already flagged it it won't let you do it a second time, so you won't run out of flags flagging it multiple times.

I also submit that if you flag often enough to need a visual indication of whether or not you've flagged a post (and are worried about running out of flags) you're probably overusing the feature. :-)

Comment: Fair comment. I am actually careful with using them, but on SU at the moment there is quite a few duplicates that pop up. Thanks Kyle, I only now released it will warn you once you have clicked the Flag Post link. I tested without trying to submit again.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like this too. As Kyle notes, [you can't flag a post twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10737/visual-indication-of-questions-you-have-flagged-for-moderation/10744#10744), so there's no danger in trying... But it's wasted time typing up a reason for the flag the second time.

And Kyle, some of us are very, very absent-minded... ;-)

Note that I'm *not* in favor of globally-displayed "flagged" indicators. We tried that, it created nothing but strife. This indicator should be visible to the person who flagged, moderators, and no one else.

Comment: +1 For visibility. This should not be global