# When question gets mod-closed, show users who flagged

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Publicise flag counts on closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109892/publicise-flag-counts-on-closed-questions)

Currently, when a moderator follows up on community flags and acts upon a question, the close message will look something like this:

> ## closed as not constructive by Kev♦ Sep 11 '11 at 11:21

Which frequently leads to angry complaints about unilateral action. How can the mod override the community's will like that! If not for the mod's decision, my question would have survived! etc. etc.

However, on Meta, it is often mentioned that when casting an unilateral close vote, mods usually follow up on community flags from users who don't have the reputation to vote to close yet.

If this is the case, why not show the flaggers' names as well to make it clear it wasn't necessarily an actively unilateral decision on a mod's behalf? After all, in this specific scenario (users flag with a specific close reason), it doesn't seem like flagging details need to be kept a secret.

> ## closed as not constructive by Kev♦ (flagged by peter1923, mega_hax0r, SeriousProgrammer) Sep 11 '11 at 11:21

or as @Daniel Fischer suggests, show the number only:

> ## closed as not constructive by Kev♦ (flagged by 4 users) Sep 11 '11 at 11:21

or a mix:

> ## closed as not constructive by Kev♦ (flagged by peter1923, mega_hax0r, and 3 other users) Sep 11 '11 at 11:21

Comment: I dunno, seems kinda clutter-y. It also doesn't help that an infinite number of users can flag a question before it gets closed, so you could potentially end up with a list of names a mile long.

Comment: Plus you'll give more fuel to ranters in the event that a Q really is closed single-handedly.

Comment: Perhaps the flag count alone would suffice? You won't get enough flags to make `flagged by 123 users` cluttery.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure flags are anonymous... not positive, but I believe that's the case.

Comment: @mike they are treated as anonymous at the moment, but the information who cast the flag is still available internally.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar moderators can see who flagged, with the exception of spam and offensive flags.

Comment: @Yannis I'd say dupe - voting to close!

Answer (score 7):

Flags are part private, we moderators generally don't reveal who exactly flagged and why. I think it would be dangerous and confusing to mix private and public flags. Seeing that the user name is revealed by flagging could mislead users into thinking that flags are not private at all.

The privacy of flags is important, and creating confusion around that might lead to users not flagging in more delicate situations.

Comment: If privacy is a concern, show the numbers only. That'd work as well

Comment: @Pekka Anyone who won't take your word for the fact that a bunch of users flagged the post probably won't be convinced by an unverifiable number.

Comment: @Asad but that's not the point. Many people get angry and start Meta rants because they get the impression it's a unilateral decision in the first place.

Comment: @Pekka Fair enough, I guess showing the number would nip *some* of those Meta rants in the bud.